# TinkerPop 3: Gremlin query to group count by edge direction

Tags: gremlin, graph-traversal, tinkerpop3

I have a vertex id to start with and wanted to get counts of in and out edges.

```
g.traversal().V().has("__id", "1234").groupCount().by(Direction.BOTH)
```

As .by() step wont accept Direction type., is there any alternative way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this nicely with [`project` step](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#project-step):

```
gremlin> graph = TinkerFactory.createModern()
==>tinkergraph[vertices:6 edges:6]
gremlin> g = graph.traversal()
==>graphtraversalsource[tinkergraph[vertices:6 edges:6], standard]
gremlin> g.V().has('name','marko').
               project('out','in').
                 by(outE().count()).
                 by(inE().count())
==>[out:3,in:0]
```

For TinkerPop 3.0.x, which didn't have `project` you could do:

```
gremlin> g.V().has('name','marko').as('out','in').
               select('out','in').
                 by(outE().count()).
                 by(inE().count())
==>[out:3,in:0]
```

Comment: Looks like "project step" is not available in TP 3.0.0. (Titan 1.0.0 uses this by default) http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/3.0.0-SNAPSHOT/